# make a script run after everything else has loaded

Tags: jquery

I am using an API which is outputting raw numbers (IE 0.938483928387443) i have set up a script that converts these to 2 decimal places however it appears this is running before the API and i need this to run as the very last thing on the page, atm i have wrapped the script up in an onclick event so i can press a button and it will convert the numbers but i would much rather have this done automatically, below is my code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#target" ).click(function() {
            $('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(5n)').addClass('formatted');
            $('.formatted').each(function(){
                var test = parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2);
                $(this).empty().append('£', test);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

im hoping once i get this running automatically i can remove the click function as it will no longer be needed.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: try to load the api before jquery.

Comment: Can you not place your logic in your button script in the callback from your call to the server? So, call the API, the data comes back in the callback function, test it and make sure its okay, and run your function. Javascript is asynchronous, so you  pretty well have to do that with anything when you are waiting for an external call to complete.

Comment: If the above isn't working, you'll need to receive some kind of event from the API that's producing the elements dynamically. Without knowing what that is or how you call it, we can't help you.

Comment: @CargoMeister thanks for this i did not know that i will go and give it a go and see what happens, thanks again.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thats for this i'll see what happens when i give it a god, the API is google's embed api pulling in data from analytics.